# How to use $select for odata call from ui5 app?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have an analytical view with the following columns - 
`sid`, `name`, `age`, `gender`, and `marks`.
I cannot use `select *` because the `gender` column creates an error in viewing the output.
Hence I have to select all the columns except `gender` to view the result.
I have an OData service that queries the view.

The OData service is as follows -

```
      service {
        "_SYS_BIC"."test_package/AN_STUDENTS" as "query"
        keys ("sid","name","age")
        aggregates always (SUM of "marks");
      }
      settings {  
        support null;  
      }
```

I can view the OData result only when I use `$select`.

`http://testservice.xsodata/query?$select=sid,name,age`

Can anyone please advise how to bind a `sap.m table` to this OData service with its item aggregation such that the `$select` part is implemented in the OData call itself directly?

Comment: Is something missing from [Dopedev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40582849/5846045)? Otherwise, please accept his answer to inform others that this issue is solved now.

Answer (score 5):

Use `parameters` option with `select` key to specify properties to retrieve.

```
<List items="{path:'query', parameters: {select: 'sid,name,age'}}">
</List>
```